# How to automate job submission and running in apache flink

Tags: apache-flink

Currently there is a provision to upload jobs jars from Flink Dashboard. This is a manual process. Is there any way to automate this process through maven command. Something like how Apache Beam has flink-runner where in you can package your maven project and it can be submitted using a maven command itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no such plugin for Maven which allows you to submit a job directly via Maven. However, after you've built your job, you can always submit the job via `flink run <JOB_JAR>` if you have a Flink cluster running.

Comment: I created a maven plugin that calls the http API uploading and running the job. Since I am new to java/ Flink, your feedback would be appreciated. https://github.com/Guru107/flinkjobuploadplugin